# RDP Certificate (SHA1 vs SHA256)

Tags: rdp

If I do

```
> Get-ChildItem -path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\Remote Desktop' | Format-List *
```

, I get a SHA1 for the Thumbprint

```
Thumbprint               : 321C02A023F0B44C3AD0C5145E90C0432F0FBG55
```

, but this is not what is presented when I RDP into the box, which is a SHA256

, so, how can I compare these two?;)

Is there any way to get the SHA256 of this certificate locally?